# Ontario HST Rebate: Filed taxes, but haven't received HST payment for December 2010?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, rebate

I have still not received my HST refund payment for December 2010.  When can I expect to receive my refund?  I filed my taxes and have just paid my balance of taxes owing, but still have not received my refund cheque that would be a direct deposit.

Comment: See http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/ontario-hst-rebate-confused-about-payment-schedules/1872#1872

Answer (score 2):

When you say you filed your taxes, did you file your 2009 taxes, or your 2010 taxes?

For the December 2010 payment, [you would need to have filed your **2009** taxes](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq.html#Q9).  (Whereas, for the final payment in June 2011, you would need to have filed your 2010 taxes.)

If you only recently filed your 2009 taxes (i.e. filed them late), then it may [take up to 8 weeks after your return has been *assessed*](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/rltd_prgrms/ntr-eng.html#sttb)  for your cheque or payment to be issued.  However, if you filed your 2009 taxes after April 30, 2011, [you won't get the December 2010 payment](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq.html#Q15).

If it has already been 8 weeks since your 2009 tax return was assessed and you did file by the deadline, then you should call the toll-free enquiries number at **1-877-627-6645**:

- You'll be calling about the *Ontario Sales Tax Transitional Benefit* (OSTTB).
- You can press 5 when prompted to hear pre-recorded information about the benefit, or, better,
- **press the star key (*)** to speak to an agent.  Mention "OSTTB".  They should be able to help you determine if you did qualify and what happened with your payment.